# Status listener on mediaplayer object in javafx 2

Tags: listener, media, javafx-2

I'm trying to make a media player with playlist in Javafx2.

I'm struggling because I want the playlist to advance to the next song when the current song ends. I was expecting a listener interface that I could implement in my playlist class but all that is on offer is that of a runnable.

Does anyone have any experience using this API that may help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement a Runnable for the setOnEndOfMedia method.

See this [sample code](https://gist.github.com/1446612) which plays a list of audio files.

I think the media events should have been handled by EventHandlers rather than Runnables and requested that they be updated to work with EventHandlers but that requires a possibly incompatible API change which hasn't been implemented yet.  So for now just use the Runnables - they work fine even though their method signatures are inconsistent with the rest of the JavaFX system.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The reason I'm wanting to use a listener is because I may have the code for playlist and player in separate classes and the playlist will need to be polled in order to return the next Media item. The sample code makes a list of MediaPlayers - it that efficient?

Comment: I used similar approach i.e. make a list of media players and then iterate through it to set the end event each mediaPlayer with the play of the next mediaPlayer. However I need to skip file if its not a valid media file (say it will error while creating the media player itself) , any suggestion ? BTW I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @Astro use [media error handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html).  Probably best to create new questions for things like this.